# Swift - Static table view cells throwing index out of range error when new section is added

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is my console output:

fatal error: Index out of range

The table array is full of static cells, and if I add more rows to the sections my app still works fine. However, if I add an additional section I receive this error. Is there a limit to the number of sections you can have in a table view?

Thanks for your help

E: I currently have 5 table view sections, if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func numberOfSections(in: UITableView)`

Asks the data source to return the number of sections in the table view.